# Find index of item in list where sum of start of list to index is greater than X

Tags: list, python-3.x, sum

I am looking for a fast implementation of the following code; using, for instance, map() or next():

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

total_so_far = 0
for i in l:
    total_so_far += i
    if total_so_far > 14:
        break

print(i)
```

The code prints the index of item in list where sum of start of list to the index is greater greater than 14.

Note: I need to continuously update the link in another loop. Therefore, a solution in numpy would probably be too slow, because it cannot update a list in-place.

Comment: what makes you think that `map` or `next` will be faster? and functional programming is not adapted to accumulation algorithms like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of [`itertools.accumulate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) together with `enumerate()` and `next()`:

```
In [1]: from itertools import takewhile

In [2]: l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [3]: next(index for index, value in enumerate(accumulate(l)) if value > 14)
Out[3]: 5
```